# Jump between PDF and source file using a document split into master and child

Tags: pdf, texmaker, editors, gedit

I am searching for an editor which is capable to jump between lines in PDF view and source view, even if the document is split into multiple files.
In my case I have a master, witch defines the general format and than a batch of files including the chapter with `\include`.

I actually tried Texmaker: I was glad with it but does not offer the wanted feature.

I tried with Gedit and its latex plugins, but Gedit keeps to crash if I even dare to open a child file.

So, is there actually a (open source) solution (for Linux/Ubuntu)?

Comment: WinEdt + Sumatra work for me, but this is not Linux bundle. I believe that exist similar combination, i.e. Sumatra + some editor work on the same way.

Comment: Have you looked at something like Kile's project feature? (With Okular as viewer, say.)

Comment: Go to [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339), look for editors with Synctex. and test some. BTW: When you used Texmaker you could also take a look on TeXstudio.

Comment: TexStudio is awesome IMHO.

Comment: Texworks does that out of the box.

Comment: Texmaker can help you to get forward/backward sync between `.pdf` and `.tex` for master and child files for sure. if you have `-synctex=1` option activated by `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` in texmaker configuration and "Define Current document as `Master Document`" by going to Texmaker `Options` menu, you should see forward/backward interaction between `.pdf` and source (`.tex`) and vice-versa.

Comment: Emacs + AUCTeX + SyncTeX works perfectly. Just type `C-c _` to set the master file in any .tex file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Texmaker does that out of the box like all the editors which support synctex (the synchronization is made by synctex) : just declare the "root" file as  the "master document" (Options) and don't use spaces or special characters in the name of the file.