# Is there a way to use forward-inverse-search from within the chapters as slave documents?

Tags: forward-inverse-search

Similar to [Texstudio and Texmaker forward and inverse search](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109827/texstudio-and-texmaker-forward-and-inverse-search) or [Jump between PDF and source file using a document split into master and child](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161579/jump-between-pdf-and-source-file-using-a-document-split-into-master-and-child), I wonder whether it's possible to use forward-inverse-search from within the included chapters as slave documents.

- I am using MiKTeX 2.9 and Texmaker 4.5.
- My LaTeX command line is
  `latex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`.
- I'm not using spaces or special characters in the file names.
- I declared the main file as master file (via Options).

What's already working, is ctrl+space from the master document and ctrl+click from the pdf (jumping directly to the slave document). Is there a direct way back from the slave document to the according position on the pdf?

Ctrl+space leads to an error message "file not found".